# pandas - Getting multiple maximum values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
indx   user_id     type        date
0      123          A Level-1  2021-01-15
1      123          A Level-1  2021-01-10
2      123          A Level-2  2021-01-10
3      123          B Level-2  2021-01-11
4      123          not_ctrgzd 2021-01-10
5      124          A Level-2  2021-02-11
6      124          B Level-1  2021-01-21
7      124          B Level-1+ 2021-02-11
8      125          not_ctrgzd 2021-01-31
9      126          A Level-1  2021-02-02
...
```

What I need is to get the rows with the most recent dates for each unique type, i.e.

```
indx   user_id     type        date
0      123          A Level-1  2021-01-15
2      123          A Level-2  2021-01-10
3      123          B Level-2  2021-01-11
4      123          not_ctrgzd 2021-01-10
5      124          A Level-2  2021-02-11
6      124          B Level-1  2021-01-21
7      124          B Level-1+ 2021-02-11
8      125          not_ctrgzd 2021-01-31
9      126          A Level-1  2021-02-02
```

And following code block is doing that

```
idx = df.groupby(['user_id','type'])['date'].transform(max) == df['date']
df[idx]
```

Now, what I can't do is to get the rows with max type value for each type(`A`,`B` and so on) so that in the end, dataframe looks like this.

```
indx   user_id     type        date
2      123          A Level-2  2021-01-10
3      123          B Level-2  2021-01-11
4      123          not_ctrgzd 2021-01-10
5      124          A Level-2  2021-02-11
7      124          B Level-1+ 2021-02-11
8      125          not_ctrgzd 2021-01-31
9      126          A Level-1  2021-02-02
```

Because B Level-1+ is greater than B Level-1 and A Level-2 is greater than A Level-1 and so on. Please notice that some rows have no categorized types(`no_ctgrzd`) which should be included in the final dataframe no matter what. Please do not hesitate to correct any parts that does not looks reasonable to you like the title :). Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a defined list of types?  If so, can we create a hierarchy in that defined list?  If so, then we can create a categorical datatype with order, then groupby sort and filter.

Comment: Yes actually following is the exact case: there is two types: A and B. And possible values for those types are: A1, A1+, A2 and B1, B1+ and B2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way with pd.CategoricalDtype:

```
#Create a catoregy and order for type
catTypeDtype = pd.CategoricalDtype(['1','1+','2'], ordered=True)

#Split the type into two helper columns to sort on category
df[['t1','t2']] = df['type'].str.extract('(?P<t1>[AB]|(?:.*))(?P<t2>.*)')

#change dtype from string to categorical
df['t2'] = df['t2'].astype(catTypeDtype)

#Sort dataframe on categorical data and date
dfs = df.sort_values(['t2','date'], ascending=[False, False])

#Groupby and take the first record after sorting
df_out = dfs.groupby(['user_id','t1'], group_keys=False, as_index=False).first()\
            .drop(['t1','t2'], axis=1)

df_out
```

Output:

```
   user_id  indx        type        date
0      123     2          A2  2021-01-10
1      123     3          B2  2021-01-11
2      123     4  not_ctrgzd  2021-01-10
3      124     5          A2  2021-02-11
4      124     6          B2  2021-01-21
5      125     8  not_ctrgzd  2021-01-31
6      126     9          A1  2021-02-02
```

---

#### Update with new data

```
catTypeDtype = pd.CategoricalDtype(['1','1+','2'], ordered=True)

df[['t1','t2']] = df['type'].str.extract('(?P<t1>[AB]|(?:.*))(?:\sLevel-)?(?P<t2>.*)')
# df

df['t2'] = df['t2'].astype(catTypeDtype)

dfs = df.sort_values(['t2','date'], ascending=[False, False])

df_out = dfs.groupby(['user_id','t1'], group_keys=False, as_index=False).first()\
            .drop(['t1','t2'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   user_id  indx        type        date
0      123     2   A Level-2  2021-01-10
1      123     3   B Level-2  2021-01-11
2      123     4  not_ctrgzd  2021-01-10
3      124     5   A Level-2  2021-02-11
4      124     7  B Level-1+  2021-02-11
5      125     8  not_ctrgzd  2021-01-31
6      126     9   A Level-1  2021-02-02
```

Comment: `not_ctgrzd` could be anything though. Would it work to replace `(?:not_ctrgzd)` with `(?:*)`

Comment: I think `(?:.*)` will work. I changed the answer to this.

Comment: Oddly, it works between rows A1 and A2 but choses A1 over A1 and A1+. Would types including spaces be the reason like let's say `Type A-1`, `Type A-1+`, `Type A-2`

Comment: I think you'll need to modify the regex a bit to get it to work with the space or dash.  If you added it to the sample data above we could figure it out.

Comment: Edited question little bit. Sorry for inconvenience at first place.

Comment: Try This: `df[['t1','t2']] = df['type'].str.extract('(?P<t1>[AB]|(?:.*))(?:\sLevel-)?(?P<t2>.*)')`

Comment: Not just modified the regex.  Regex is a beast in its own.   Basically added an optional non-capturing group to handle the space and Level-.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228593/discussion-between-zodiac645-and-scott-boston).

Answer (score 3):

Exactly your approach - just derive value you are grouping by.

```
idx = df.groupby(['user_id',
                  np.where(df.type.str.match("[A,B][1,2]"), df.type.str.replace(r"([A-B])[1,2]",r"\1-", regex=True), df.type)]
                )['date'].transform(max) == df['date']
df[idx]
```

|  | idx | user_id | type | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 123 | A1 | 2021-01-15 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 3 | 123 | B2 | 2021-01-11 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 4 | 123 | not_ctrgzd | 2021-01-10 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 5 | 124 | A2 | 2021-02-11 00:00:00 |
| 6 | 7 | 124 | B1 | 2021-02-11 00:00:00 |
| 7 | 8 | 125 | not_ctrgzd | 2021-01-31 00:00:00 |
| 8 | 9 | 126 | A1 | 2021-02-02 00:00:00 |

Comment: Sorry for updating part by part, but my real column values are containing '-', i.e. A-1, A-1+, A-2. Guess I ve constructed a wrong example in the question to shorten it. That regex matching would fail here I suppose.

Comment: you'd need to amend the regex a little. `"[A,B][1,2][+]?"` for A1+ etc,  for inserted hython I'll leave it to you.  same method just update regex